# Can we remotely run and debug Python code from a Docker container using Spyder

Tags: python, docker, spyder, remote-debugging

JetBrains PyCharm is able to remotely run and debug Python code from inside a Docker container. Also, it is able to do the same task using an Anaconda environment.

I would like to ask if it possible to perform such a task (using either Anaconda or Docker) with the Spyder IDE.

My objective is to run and debug Python code using a Docker container that lives remotely to a different machine. The Docker container contains the appropriate Python interpreter as well as the Python modules I need.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spyder doc it is possible for conda environment using ssh : http://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-an-external-kernel.

For Docker container the same steps should work according to this [issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7147).

But I have not tried this myself.

**EDIT :** Otherwise, if you like to edit your remote code as well as running it. You can use Visual Studio Code Insider (available [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)) It is a preliminary version of what should be included natively in Visual Studio Code soon.

Comment: I have connected the Spyder with a remote IPython kernel and I can run Python commands to the terminal inside Spyder. However, I cannot edit and debug Python code from Spyder IDE. Also, there is not way to share the local working space of project files with the IPython kernel. One workaround I have found is to share the files with a network mounted drive which sounds a bad solution. Have you ever develop Python software using a local IDE but a remote environment (Docker container with Python interpreter, libraries, dependencies)?

Comment: Hi @EfstathiosChatzikyriakidis did you manage to figure out how can we debug the code using Spyder? I also manage to connect to kernel via ssh but I would like to debug the code too :(